# How to use aiopg pool in multi-threaded application?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a python 3.4.3, postgreSQL 9.4, aiopg-0.7.0.  An example of multi-threaded applications, was taken from this site. How to use the pool? The thread hangs when the operation of the select.

```
import time
import asyncio
import aiopg
import functools
from threading import Thread, current_thread, Event
from concurrent.futures import Future

class B(Thread):
   def __init__(self, start_event):
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.loop = None
       self.tid = None
       self.event = start_event

   def run(self):
       self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
       asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
       self.tid = current_thread()
       self.loop.call_soon(self.event.set)
       self.loop.run_forever()

   def stop(self):
       self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)

   def add_task(self, coro):
       """this method should return a task object, that I
         can cancel, not a handle"""
      def _async_add(func, fut):
          try:
              ret = func()
              fut.set_result(ret)
          except Exception as e:
              fut.set_exception(e)

       f = functools.partial(asyncio.async, coro, loop=self.loop)
       if current_thread() == self.tid:
           return f() # We can call directly if we're not going between threads.
       else:
           # We're in a non-event loop thread so we use a Future
           # to get the task from the event loop thread once
           # it's ready.
           fut = Future()
           self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(_async_add, f, fut)
           return fut.result()

   def cancel_task(self, task):
       self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(task.cancel)


@asyncio.coroutine
def test(pool, name_task):
    while True:
        print(name_task, 'running')
        with (yield from pool.cursor()) as cur:
            print(name_task, " select. ")
            yield from cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM test")
            count = yield from cur.fetchone()
            print(name_task, ' Result: ', count)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(3)

@asyncio.coroutine
def connect_db():
    dsn = 'dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s' % ('testdb', 'user', 'passw', '127.0.0.1')
    pool = yield from aiopg.create_pool(dsn)
    print('create pool type =', type(pool))
    # future.set_result(pool)
    return (pool)

event = Event()
b = B(event)
b.start()
event.wait() # Let the loop's thread signal us, rather than sleeping
loop_db = asyncio.get_event_loop()
pool = loop_db.run_until_complete(connect_db())
time.sleep(2)
t = b.add_task(test(pool, 'Task1'))  # This is a real task
t = b.add_task(test(pool, 'Task2'))

while True:
    time.sleep(10)

b.stop()
```

Not return result in 'yield from cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM test")'

Comment: may helps: http://pylover.dobisel.com/posts/aiopg-aiopg_sa-and-aiopg8000/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short: you cannot share aiopg pool object from different event loops.

Every `aiopg.Pool` is coupled to event loop. If you don't specify `loop` parameter explicitly it is taken from `asyncio.get_event_loop()` call.

So it your example you have a pool coupled to event loop from main thread.

When you execute db query from separate thread you trying to accomplish it by executing thread's loop, not the main one. It doesn't work.